# Как поставить лимиты на количество результатов поиска, fuseJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, полнотекстовый-поиск

Я реализовывал поиск по массиву объектов при помощи [FuseJS](https://www.fusejs.io/) и столкнулся с проблемой - не могу ограничить количество выдаваемых объектов. Единственное решение, которое я нашёл, - использовать `splice`, но я не уверен в правильности данного метода.

```
let fuse = FuseSearch(list);
let data = fuse.search(searchQuery).splice(0, 10);
```

Comment: Покажите код, который вы реализовали

Comment: https://www.fusejs.io/api/methods.html#:~:text=Denotes%20the%20max%20number%20of%20returned%20search%20results

Comment: `let fuse = FuseSearch(list);

let data = fuse.search(searchQuery).splice(0, 10);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Methods -> [search](https://www.fusejs.io/api/methods.html#search)

> The options:
>
> limit (type: number): Denotes the max number of returned search
> results.

```js
const list = [{"title":"Old Man's War","author":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Scalzi"}},{"title":"The Lock Artist","author":{"firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Hamilton"}},{"title":"HTML5","author":{"firstName":"Remy","lastName":"Sharp"}},{"title":"Right Ho Jeeves","author":{"firstName":"P.D","lastName":"Woodhouse"}},{"title":"The Code of the Wooster","author":{"firstName":"P.D","lastName":"Woodhouse"}},{"title":"Thank You Jeeves","author":{"firstName":"P.D","lastName":"Woodhouse"}},{"title":"The DaVinci Code","author":{"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Brown"}},{"title":"Angels & Demons","author":{"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Brown"}},{"title":"The Silmarillion","author":{"firstName":"J.R.R","lastName":"Tolkien"}},{"title":"Syrup","author":{"firstName":"Max","lastName":"Barry"}},{"title":"The Lost Symbol","author":{"firstName":"Dan","lastName":"Brown"}},{"title":"The Book of Lies","author":{"firstName":"Brad","lastName":"Meltzer"}},{"title":"Lamb","author":{"firstName":"Christopher","lastName":"Moore"}},{"title":"Fool","author":{"firstName":"Christopher","lastName":"Moore"}},{"title":"Incompetence","author":{"firstName":"Rob","lastName":"Grant"}},{"title":"Fat","author":{"firstName":"Rob","lastName":"Grant"}},{"title":"Colony","author":{"firstName":"Rob","lastName":"Grant"}},{"title":"Backwards, Red Dwarf","author":{"firstName":"Rob","lastName":"Grant"}},{"title":"The Grand Design","author":{"firstName":"Stephen","lastName":"Hawking"}},{"title":"The Book of Samson","author":{"firstName":"David","lastName":"Maine"}},{"title":"The Preservationist","author":{"firstName":"David","lastName":"Maine"}},{"title":"Fallen","author":{"firstName":"David","lastName":"Maine"}},{"title":"Monster 1959","author":{"firstName":"David","lastName":"Maine"}}];

const fuseOptions = {
  keys: ["title", "author.firstName"]
};

const fuse = new Fuse(list, fuseOptions);

const searchPattern = "Stephen";

const result = fuse.search(searchPattern, {
  limit: 2
});

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fuse.js/dist/fuse.js"></script>
```

---

Кстати, вам понравится как [реализована](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/blob/cbc246cd98d62524c4ea62067c8ffec0b20360e2/src/core/index.js#L99) обработка `limit`:

```js
if (isNumber(limit) && limit > -1) {
  results = results.slice(0, limit)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, видимо я что-то пропустил в документации